# How do I install Groovy 2.5 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, java, jvm

`sudo apt-get install groovy`
provides me with:

```
groovy -v
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.8.0_131 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

However, this version of Groovy is very old. How do I get the newest one installed? - 2.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by following the guide here: http://groovy-lang.org/install.html

```
curl -s get.sdkman.io | bash

source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

sdk install groovy
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sudo apt-get install groovy2
$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_144 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: as the old version is still there the alternatives switcher method should be able to change the invoked version "on the fly" - maybe you even already had it there but it was simply not the default. `sudo update-alternatives --config groovy`